# Replace Whole Line Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, replace, fs

I want to read a text file, then remove a whole line from the text file if the user's id is found and then resave the text file.

To clarify each line in the text file looks like the below (but without the bullet points)

- John Smith 1002931029012901
- Jenny Simmons 12901920129019

So I made the following code below.

```
client.on('guildMemberRemove',(member) => {
    var text = fs.readFileSync("textfile.txt", "utf8");
    text.split('\n').filter(function(line){ 
    return line.indexOf( member.id ) == -1;
    }).join('\n')
fs.writeFile("emails.txt", text, () => {});
console.log("Working");
});
```

However, the line with the id doesn't appear to be getting deleted. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the result of your manipulations because every time you are creating a new string.

```
var text = fs.readFileSync("textfile.txt", "utf8");
text = text.split('\n').filter(function(line){ 
  return line.indexOf( member.id ) == -1;
}).join('\n')
```

The rest of the code can remain the same.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! Knew I forgot something obvious.